# How do I make people stop running with a command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map and when I give them slowness it's still possible for them to walk a little faster (or run with slowness on) but I want them still walking.  Can anyone can help me?  It has to be a command.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to detect when a player is sprinting via sprintOnecm statistic and give them a higher slowness effect when they are sprinting such that sprinting and walking would be no different. Just make sure the player can't jump using a high jump boost level.

Answer (score 0):

Try using soul sand, possibly with ice under.

That will slow them down considerably.  You can sprint jump to somewhat bypass it, because the air above is not slowed, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to do this, but each one has its disadvantages...

1. Give the player blindness using the `/effect` command. Blinded players can't sprint. However, the player will also have limited vision.
2. Drain the player's hunger. This cannot be instant though, but again you can use the `/effect` command to give them hunger.
3. Just give the player a high slowness level. They can still sprint, but at a certain level sprinting will still be really slow like normal walking.
4. Or just use RikerW's method, but also give the player a "corrupt" jump boost effect to disable the player from jumping. Use levels 128–250, according to the wiki.

Comment: I'm ALWAYS using the latest version just so you know.  right now its 1.9.1-pre3